# merging data of two data sets

Tags: linux, files, merge

I am attempting to merge two datasets.....

File 1 is a single column

```
JDay list 1 to 366
```

File 2 has 3 columns

```
2002 1  9.5938
2002 2  9.5938
2002 3  -28672.0000
2002 5  -28672.0000
```

At times there is data missing as can be seen in the file 2 example where JDAY 4 is missing. I am looking to get these two files together matching the correct JDAY flag and printing the data. Also I am looking to have any missing JDAYS given the missing data flag of -9999 in order to tell what days were missing.

The new file should look like this....

```
2002 1  9.5938
2002 2  9.5938
2002 3  -28672.0000
2002 4  -9999
2002 5  -28672.0000
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This should work

Create a file `merge.awk` with the following code in it

```
BEGIN{
    getline<ARGV[1]; l=$3; r=$5; ARGV[1]=""
}
$1 != year { if (x) while(x <= r) print year, x++, -9999
    year=$1
    x=l
}
$2 < l{
    print
    next
}
{
    while($2 > x) print year, x++, -9999
    print
    ++x
    next
}
$2 > r{
    while(x <= r) print year, x++, -9999
    print
    next
}
END{
    while(x <= r) print year, x++, -9999
}
```

followed by

```
awk -f merge.awk file1 file2
```

Comment: Iruvar I tried the code you have provided. However, it appears that missing days are not being added or the -9999 flag when the file is being corrected. In my case for 2002 year there are only 345 days of data. It is also not showing the last row which should be 2002 366 -9999.

Comment: @stormctr2,  the updated version should work